# Logical Error for SetDay Function

Tags: c++

These are member functions, where mm, dd, and yy are the only data members. For some reason when I run it, the first object is ok, but then on the second object it returns as false. and continues to ask the user for input. I know for sure there's something wrong with my validation for setDay, because it's asking the user to keep inputting values, despite the values being valid. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

//setDay function
bool Date::setDay( int d ){

```
    bool validate = false;
    int monthsPerYear = 12;

    int date[monthsPerYear] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
            if ( mm == monthsPerYear && d <= date[i]){
                    dd = d;
                    validate = true;
            }

    }

    return(validate);
```

}

//input member function

void Date::input(){

```
    int m, y, d;

    do{
            cout << "Enter month: ";
            cin >> m;
            mm = m;
    } while(!setMonth(m));

    do{
            cout << "Enter date: ";
            cin >> d;
            dd = d;
    } while (!setDay(d));

    do{
            cout << "Enter year: ";
            cin >> y;
            yy = y;
    } while (!setYear(y));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you read your own code :-)

```
   bool validate = false;
    int monthsPerYear = 12;

    int date[monthsPerYear] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
            if ( mm == monthsPerYear && d <= date[i]){
                    dd = d;
                    validate = true;
            }

    }
```

It only accepts dates in month 12 `mm == monthsPerYear &&`

Also you should loop from 0 to 11 not 1 to 12. Computer aray indexes start at 0.

But you dont need loops. YOur code should just read

```
if(d <= date[mm]){
  dd=d;
  validate = true;
}
```

PS: Learn to use a debugger to step through your code. You didn't say what platform you are running on so I cannot tell you how to do it. But you have to learn how